# Imprimir sobre factura pre diseñada Java

Tags: java, impresión

Tengo que hacer una funcionalidad en la que se me solicita imprimir sobre una factura prediseñada por una imprenta (Es una Factura tipo C de AFIP personalizada por la empresa [Similar a esta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90DmA.jpg)).

Mi idea es poder poner la medida de la hoja en la cual se va a realizar la impresión (si es posible en centímetros) y luego poder agregar a que altura y ancho de la misma se ubicaría el texto a imprimir.

No se muy bien como que se puede hacer, se que existe la clase PrinterJob (En este topic entiendo que pregunta algo similar pero no estoy seguro de que haga lo que quiero, y tampoco se si se puede hacer esto en alguna medida que no sea pixeles
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314649/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-a-printed-page-in-java
)

Cualquier recomendación para hacerlo de esta forma, con un generador de reporte o alguna otra herramienta que pueda hacer esto mas fácil de lo que lo pienso es bienvenido.

Aclaraciones: Por una cuestión de requerimientos no puedo hacer la facturación electrónica a través de la API de AFIP ni puedo imprimir todo junto con el fondo. Debo hacerlo sobre la factura prediseñada sí o sí.

Comment: Pues sin poder utilizar una API y sin poder imprimirlo todo con el fondo va a ser francamente raro, además que pueden generarse unos problemas increibles, si por ejemplo en un mes cambian el tamaño del papel a rediseñarlo todo

Comment: Actualmente lo hacen en un sistema antiguo que tienen. Mas allá de lo que tengo que hacer queria saber si existe alguna forma de poder indicar tres cosas a la hora de imprimir:
El tamaño de la Hoja y los margenes de impresion en la misma.

Comment: Si, por supuesto se pueden tener en cuenta los margenes y tamaños de la hoja la cuestión es cómo lo sabe el programa mmmmm lo que se me ocurre es que incluyas en un menu bar un frame para que el usuario pueda especificar o modificar medidas de papel, margen y esas cosas y que esas medidas se queden guardadas en algún lugar pero el trabajo de las formulas para ajustar la impresión a medidas te llevará tiempo

Comment: Algo en este sentido https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html aunque creo que concretamente esto no te serviría ya que no te rencomendaría trabajar sencillamente con un área

Comment: Sisi, la idea es tener configurado eso a mano en una sección. Gracias por la información! voy a mirar eso.